# minimum value gives ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I hope to use the following code to calculte a field called min, where it's the minimum of value `2`, field `value1` and field `value2`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"value1":[3,2,1],"value2":[3,2,3],"value3":[1,1,1]})
```

If I use

```
df["min"]=min(2,df['value1'],df['value2'])
```

I got the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The expected output is:

```
   value1  value2  value3  min
0       3       3       1    2
1       2       2       1    2
2       1       3       1    1
```

Comment: `df["min"]= df.min(axis=1)`

Comment: @rhug123 thanks, the first value of value1/value2 should be both 3, and there could be other field like value3, please see the edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).min(axis=1).clip(upper=2)
```

If just two columns required:

```
cols = ['value1','value2']
df[cols].min(axis=1).clip(upper=2)
```

Comment: nice one, did not think about it

Comment: @rhug123, it will take `value3` into account, I edit field `value3` to make it obvious

Comment: @rhug123, as we only need min of `2`, `value1` and `value2`